# Is this question too broad or off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I encountered this question in my review queue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38307148/how-to-change-forms-from-left-to-right-and-disable-auto-open

It doesn't include a MCVE, but it also isn't asking for debugging help.

I eventually skipped it, because I couldn't really pinpoint how to flag it. Should this question be flagged, and if so, how? How should questions that basically amount to 'write my code' be flagged?

Comment: I would have gone for *Too broad* myself, but that's the beauty of review queue, it takes several people to decide how it should be effectively flagged.

Comment: I would close it as off topic in this case since the question is asking for help modifying existing functionality without presenting said existing code.